# Post a picture on facebook

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I want to publish a picture with a title (@name) and a texte (@caption) on facebook when my quiz is over.
I try to put my picture in an UIImage then i called her with @picture int the attachment but it doesn't work at all.

Have you a piece of code to show me how i can do this?

Thank you

Flo

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
- (void) uploadPhoto:(UIImage *) img caption:(NSString *) caption delegate:(NSObject<FBRequestDelegate> *) delegate{
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    img, @"picture",
                                    nil];
    if (caption != nil) {
        [params setObject:params forKey:@"message"];
    }

    [self requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" 
                          andParams:params 
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                        andDelegate:delegate];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But i did with an another method. I send the picture directly in the attachment with an another NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your method. I believe:

```
[params setObject:params forKey:@"message"];
```

should read:

```
[params setObject: caption forKey:@"message"];
```